# VBA Scenario Deleter Macro only Deletes odd macros

Tags: vba

Hello I wrote a VBA Macro to delete my What if Scenarios I have 84 of them and they are named 1,2,3,4,....,84 so I wrote this code

```
Sub Dismantle()
For Count = 1 To 84
    ActiveSheet.Scenarios(Count).Delete
Next

End Sub
```

But it only deletes scenarios 1,3,5,7,9.....,83 then returns the error: Unable to get Scenarios property of the worksheet class. 
This means there is no scenario with the name count for it to delete (I think anyway)
Running again it deletes the first third ect again so its skipping every second scenario.

Comment: When you delete scenario #1, then what was #2 is now #1, and so on. Work backwards from 84 to 1 instead.

Comment: Oh ok thats how it interprets it, I want count to be the name of the scenario so ActiveSheet.Scenarios(Count).Delete would delete the scenario named count.

Comment: In your case "count" is a number, not a string, so you're deleting by index position, not by name. If you want to delete by name then you need to first give each scenario a distinct name - e.g. "scen_001"

Comment: The names of the scenarios are "1","2","3",....,"84" do I will just convert to string.

Comment: You can try - `ActiveSheet.Scenarios(CStr(Count)).Delete`

Comment: @DirkDouwes if my answer worked then please accept it ;p

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub Dismantle()
    For Count = 84 to 1 step -1
        ActiveSheet.Scenarios(Count).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

You were so close :-)

Or, for more flexibility:

```
Do While ActiveSheet.Scenarios.Count > 0
    ActiveSheet.Scenarios(1).Delete()
Loop
```